# Why write vectors in the form of contravariant components and covariant basis vectors?

Tags: vectors, transformation

I recently started learning about dual basis vectors.

In a textbook, the author says that writing 2D vectors in the form of 
$$\vec A = A^x \vec e_1 +A^y \vec e_2=A_x \vec e^1 + A_y \vec e^2$$

serves to emphasize an important fact:

> You can combine contravariant components with covariant basis vectors, or combine covariant components with contravariant basis vectors to define a quantity (such as vector $\vec A$) that is invariant under transformation of coordinates (e.g. rotation of coodinate system).

He then proceeded to say that the above statment should seem *reasonable* because covariant quantitites transform using a direct transformation matrix $D$ and contravariant quantities transform using an inverse transformatix $I$, with the effect $$D=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix} I=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$$$DI=1$$ which is the identity matrix. So combining such quantities guarantees that the result is unaffected by transformation of coordinates.

I am finding it hard to see how that is *reasonable*. Is there an explicit example that shows what the author actually means?

Comment: I would call them $A_1,A_2,A^1$ and $A^2$, not with $x,y$.